# validate values in two data frame

Tags: r, dplyr

I have two data frames with approx. 1 million records now I am trying to check if Uniq_ID present in df2 and not present in df1 for city = mum. then mutate df2 with 1 or 0 for true or false.

```
df1 <- data.frame(ID =c("DEV2962","KTN2252","ANA2719","ITI2624","DEV2698","HRT2921","","KTN2624","ANA2548","ITI2535","DEV2732","HRT2837","ERV2951","KTN2542","ANA2813","ITI2210"),
                  city=c("del","mum","mum","pun","bang","mum","triv","vish","mum","mum","bang","vish","mum","kol","noi","mum"))
df2 <- data.frame(Uniq_ID =c("DEV2962","KTN2252","ANA2719","H7236","DEV2692","HRT2921","","KTN2624","ANA2548","ITI2535","DEV2732","HRT2831","ERV2951","KTN2542","ANA2813","ITI2210"),
                  city=c("del","mum","bho","pun","mum","chen","mum","vish","mum","mum","bang","mum","mum","kol","noi","mum"))
```

Comment: This : `df2$ID_not_in_df1 <- as.integer(!df2$ID %in% unique(df1$ID))` ?

Comment: i have tried this but i have have a filter condition for city in mum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign 1 to `Uniq_ID` in `df2` which is not present in `df1` and which has `city = 'mum'`.

```
df2$ID_not_in_df1 <- +(!df2$Uniq_ID %in% unique(df1$ID) & df2$city == 'mum')
df2

#   Uniq_ID city ID_not_in_df1
#1  DEV2962  del             0
#2  KTN2252  mum             0
#3  ANA2719  bho             0
#4    H7236  pun             0
#5  DEV2692  mum             1
#6  HRT2921 chen             0
#7           mum             0
#8  KTN2624 vish             0
#9  ANA2548  mum             0
#10 ITI2535  mum             0
#11 DEV2732 bang             0
#12 HRT2831  mum             1
#13 ERV2951  mum             0
#14 KTN2542  kol             0
#15 ANA2813  noi             0
#16 ITI2210  mum             0
```

Comment: `df2$Uniq_ID %in% unique(df1$ID) & df2$city == 'mum'` is a logical condition giving `TRUE`/`FALSE` values. `+` converts `TRUE` to 1 and `FALSE` to 0.

Answer (score 1):

We can use base R in that case. Does this work:

```
> df2$ID_not_in_df1 <- ifelse(!df2$Uniq_ID %in% df1$ID & df2$city == 'mum', 1 ,0)
> df2
   Uniq_ID city ID_not_in_df1
1  DEV2962  del             0
2  KTN2252  mum             0
3  ANA2719  bho             0
4    H7236  pun             0
5  DEV2692  mum             1
6  HRT2921 chen             0
7           mum             0
8  KTN2624 vish             0
9  ANA2548  mum             0
10 ITI2535  mum             0
11 DEV2732 bang             0
12 HRT2831  mum             1
13 ERV2951  mum             0
14 KTN2542  kol             0
15 ANA2813  noi             0
16 ITI2210  mum             0
>
```

Comment: in my actual data i have many col variables so by default left join will join by all column, my question was to work like across or row wise all unique_id in df2 for city in mumbai and then check if they are present in df1